# wxPython: is there a way to show a sort arrow indicator in the column header of a wx.dataview.DataViewListCtrl?

Tags: python, list, sorting, wxpython

Python v3.7.9 x64; wxPython v4.1.0; MS Windows 10 x64

As the title of this question states, does anyone know of a way to show a sort arrow indicator on the column header of a `wx.dataview.DataViewListCtrl` widget? I have literally exhausted my search abilities and have been going at it for days. I have zero idea if this is possible, although I would think it is since Windows has sort arrows in column headers. A native sort arrow would be preferable, although if this is not possible, then adding graphics for a sort arrow would be ok.

Using `wx.dataview.EVT_DATAVIEW_COLUMN_HEADER_CLICK` event, I have completed my own sorting, but it would be beneficial if the end-user could visually see a sorting arrow indicating that column is able to be sorted. Otherwise, how will the end-user know.

If this is doable then some example code, links, or anything would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: One thing you could try is to use unicode symbols. For example: arrows (▲ ▼). It is a portion of text that you can append to the text of the header.
http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html

Comment: That's a great idea, and that's what I'll do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out if anyone else ever has this problem and it is very simple.

After creating the `DataViewListCtrl` object you can choose particular columns, or make them all sortable.

```
self.list_control = wx.dataview.DataViewListCtrl(parent)  # DataViewListCtrl object
```

If you want only one column sortable:

```
first_column = self.list_control.Columns[0]  # get the first column
first_column.SetSortable(sortable=True)  # make first column sortable
```

If you want to make all columns sortable:

```
for column in self.list_control.Columns:
    column.SetSortable(sortable=True)
```